# Why .attr("data-number", num_to_string ) and .data('number') are working in combination?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want change repeatedly the attribute value of `data-number="2"` when `.next` is clicked. It works at the first attempt that means the browser gives data-number value as 3. But when I click next times, it doesn't change. It remains 3.
Here my code:

```
<a class="prev" data-number="1">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" data-number="2">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready( function(){
        $('a.next').on( 'click', function(){
        var image_num = parseInt($(this).data('number')) + 1 ;
        var num_to_string = image_num.toString();
        var prev_value = $(this).attr("data-number", num_to_string );
            console.log(prev_value);

        } );
    } );
</script>
```

I want to have the value as 3, 4, 5 ....

Comment: You can find the reason why your code isn't working in @Barmar answer in the link I provided. It's good to know why your code is not working, rather than just copying a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't update the intended `data-number`-attribute, because you have to use [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) as well to update it. So I replaced this line:

```
$(this).attr("data-number", num_to_string )
```

with this line:

```
$(this).data("number", num_to_string);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a.next').on('click', function () {
    var image_num = parseInt($(this).data('number')) + 1;
    var num_to_string = image_num.toString();
    var prev_value = $(this).data('number', +num_to_string);
    console.log(num_to_string);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="prev" data-number="1">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" data-number="2">&#10095;</a>
</div>
```

The reason for this behaviour is that jquery handles data-attribute (`data-number`) differently than ordinary attributes like `id` because when dealing with data-attributes the DOM-element is actually not altered unlike with ordinary attributes, as this [link](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/data-and-attr-in-jquery) states.

That's why both methods `data` and `attr` work different and can therefore not be used in combination as they are used in the question, because `attr` works with updated DOM-values but `data` does not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or just use `data` all the way through.

Comment: Best answer, I just updated my answer.

Comment: This is the proper way of using `data` attributes, but it doesn't explain why `$(this).attr("data-number", num_to_string )` doesn't work. Shouldn't it work? :thinking:

Comment: @Alisson: Good question, hope my explaination makes sense to everyone.

Comment: @EMHossain: You are welcome!

Answer (score -1):

If you use `data()` jQuery will automatically cast numeric data attribute values to number

```js
  $('a.next').on('click', function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    // increment the data object value of number property 
    $el.data().number ++;

    console.log('New number:', $el.data('number'))
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="next" data-number="2">Next</a>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and doesn't even provide an explanation to why OP's code doesn't work.